# Switch display on mouse focus

Tags: macos, focus, switch-statement, multiple-monitors, onfocus

How to switch display on mouse focus in mac os x?

I need a monitor switch on mouse focus.

I didn't find such extension.

Comment: A very old question but did you find anything?